# Attacks on Aes (128-192-256)

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography

I have a direct question 
Is there any practical attacks on the AES cryptosystem (128-192-256 keys)

Comment: No, not that we (the public) know of.

Answer (score 4):

There are practical [side-channel attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/how-practical-are-side-channel-attacks-and-how-much-of-a-concern-are-they?rq=1) against implementations of AES, but there are not any practical cryptanalytic attacks against the abstract algorithm.

The best cryptanalytic attack against the complete cipher in a reasonable attack model is probably [the biclique attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2419/29554), which only knocks a few bits off the key. The [related key attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5120/29554) against AES have attack models which are unreasonable when using AES as a block cipher to preserve confidentiality, and so are less/non applicable even though the bottom line of the computational cost of the attack is more pronounced.

For more information, you might investigate the following question/answers: [How is encryption broken today](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/45229/29554)? While that question/answer(s) is not specific towards AES, most if not all of the information is relevant.

Comment: Thank you,  I've read about Biclique_attack and also about the quantum attack but I didn't find any real proof!!!